# Get web service message when I get 422 error using SpringFramework Android Rest Client

Tags: android, rest, http-post

I'm developing an Android application that connects to a Web service. From the web service I get this error:

```
POST request for "xxx" resulted in 422 (Unprocessable Entity); invoking error handler
```

I'm using SpringFramework Rest Client for Android, and I connect to the web service with this code:

```
public static User sendUserPersonalData(User userProfileData)
{
    try
    {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));
        HttpEntity<User> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<User>(userProfileData, requestHeaders);

        GsonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(messageConverter);

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        String url = URL_BASE_WEB + USER_PERSONAL_DATA_CALL;
        ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, User.class);

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But, the web service also returns a JSON string like this one:

```
{
    "email": [
        "is invalid"
    ],
    "birthday": [
        "is invalid"
    ],
    "startday": [
        "is invalid"
    ],
    "sex_preference": [
        "can't be blank"
    ],
    "password": [
        "is too long (maximum is 4 characters)"
    ]
}
```

**How can I get it even if I get an Exception?**

Comment: post some code from your `onErrorListener` or something like that..

Comment: I don't have an `onErrorListener`. I don't have more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch the [`RestClientException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html) like this :

```
  try{
     ....
     restTemplate.exchange(...);
  }catch(RestClientException e){
     //process exception
     if(e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException){
         String errorResponse=((HttpStatusCodeException)e).getResponseBodyAsString();
         //now you have the response, construct json from it, and extract the errors
     }

  }
```

Have a look at the javadocs for [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), [`RestClientException`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientException.html).

Comment: Why not `catch(HttpStatusCodeException hsce)` ?

Answer (score 0):

My approach on this one was to add a multiple catch in order to make sure that each individual error is handled.

Also pay attention to:

1. What you log because the response is escaped Java characters (eg.: /u733) for this you can use **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava()** as in the following example
2. Since you have to do with problematic reponses (lets say not stable) also catch **HttpMessageNotReadableException** which occur when an unexpected object exists in the response.

> ```
> try {
>           return restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, responseType, uriVariables);
>       }catch(HttpStatusCodeException e) {
>           String errorResponse = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
>           LOG.error("RestResponse: {}", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(errorResponse));
>           throw e;
>       } catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
>           LOG.error("Unexpected object in the response", e);
>           throw e;
>       }catch (Exception e){
>           LOG.error("Unexpected error", e);
>           throw new InvalidDataException("Unexpected error");
>       }
> ```